# ionic2 how to display Json data?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i am trying to fetch data and display it in ionic 2 but i an having error that i dont understand. this is the url to my json data http://thethinker.com.ng/techwand/usr.php. i just want to display some of the data in a list format. the console.log(data); display the data in the console but i get errors when trying to sort the data out. using {{item.data.first_name}} {{item.data.last_name}}

This is my error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:59262:25)
    at MapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:46400:76)
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45993:35)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:15510:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:59691:38)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9655)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4616:37)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9576)
    at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4831)
```

This is my typescript class

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { RedditService } from '../../app/serve/RedditServices';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import { DetailsPage } from '../details/details';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';
    /**
     * Generated class for the RedditPage page.
     *
     * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
     * on Ionic pages and navigation.
     */
    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-reddit',
      templateUrl: 'reddit.html',
    })
    export class RedditPage {
      http: any;
     baseUrl: String;
    items: any;


      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private redditservice:RedditService,http: Http) {
         this.http= http;
     this.baseUrl ="http://thethinker.com.ng/techwand/usr.php";
        this.getallpost();
      }



    ngOnInit(){
        this.getallpost();
    }



    getPosts(category, limit){
        this.redditservice.getPosts().subscribe(data => {
            this.items =data.data;
    });
    }


    getallpost(){
      this.http.get(this.baseUrl).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
            this.items =     data.data;
console.log(data);
    }); 
    }

    }
```

this is some of the json data

```
{
success: true,
-data: (3)[
-{
first_name: "Kayla",
last_name: "Leftwich",
email: "kleftwich0@cnbc.com",
gender: "Female",
image: http://dummyimage.com/202x140.png/cc0000/ffffff,
country: "United States",
state: "North Carolina",
phone_number: "1-(704)808-0271",
professional: "Community Outreach Specialist"
},
-{
first_name: "Jeniffer",
last_name: "Concklin",
email: "jconcklin1@seesaa.net",
gender: "Female",
image: http://dummyimage.com/104x134.png/5fa2dd/ffffff,
country: "United States",
state: "Ohio",
phone_number: "1-(937)878-1803",
professional: "Nuclear Power Engineer"
},
-{
first_name: "Gonzalo",
last_name: "Byk",
email: "gbyk2@twitter.com",
gender: "Male",
image: http://dummyimage.com/112x100.png/dddddd/000000,
country: "United States",
state: "North Carolina",
phone_number: "1-(336)376-6805",
professional: "Account Coordinator"
}
]
}
```

I am using this tutorial https://www.joshmorony.com/using-http-to-fetch-remote-data-from-a-server-in-ionic-2/ but it only works for thier api and i am trying to use mine

Comment: could be malformed json..print the response `.map(res => {console.log(res); return res.json()})` and test your json in some online formatter.

Comment: STILL  not working

Comment: does it log the json?

Comment: yes is ther another way

Comment: it is malformed `image: http://dummyimage.com/202x140.png/cc0000/ffffff,` your image data needs double quotes

Comment: just removed the image still not working.

Comment: use  http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to correct your json. You need double quotes for success and data keys

Comment: This was helpful but .just one thing no error idoes not display the data but just draws the list divider lines

Comment: I didnt get that sorry..

Comment: i mean the error is gone but the data does not display............. it just show eight lines without any data between them

Comment: some issue in your html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you are trying to display something like `item.first_name` in your iteration (I assume you have an iteration). There is no such property like `first_name` in your data now after you making changes to your JSON. And I would make some changes to your code as well. We usually keep http-requests in a service, which returns an Observable (in your case), which we then subscribe to in the component. So in your `RedditService` with the following function:

```
getData(){
  return this.http.get('https://thethinker.com.ng/techwand/usr.php')
     .map(res => res.json().data)
}
```

and in your component subscribe. Also keep all unnecessary things from your constructor. We have the OnInit to handle things that are not *needed* in constructor.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.redditService.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.items = data;
    });
}
```

Then you can iterate your data in template like:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item.data}} {{item.two}}
</ion-item>
```

This will print the first name and last name. You seem to have an odd naming convention going on there, so I'd suggest you look into it :)

Here's a **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4MW7NweW74lnNH3wAvRR?p=preview)**